# Is Cartesian Product same as SQL Full Outer Join?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Is Cartesian Product same as Full Outer Join found in Relational Database SQL?  I ask because I am taking a Discrete Mathematics course and I just want a better understanding of how what I am studying (Cartesian Product) applies to or maps to what I do when developing software (SQL Joins).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No: the Cartesian product is not the same as SQL [`FULL OUTER JOIN`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_full.asp).

For example: if A = {1,2} and B = ∅, then A × B = {1,2} × ∅ = ∅, i.e. the Cartesian product yield the empty set. But, since `FULL OUTER JOIN` does not require each record in the two joined tables to have a matching record, if B is empty and A is not, `FULL OUTER JOIN` will still return some rows.

However, [`CROSS JOIN`](http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php) will return the [Cartesian product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of rows from tables in the join.

The link between is SQL and discrete mathematics is [relational algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra) (cf. [Codd's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_theorem)) if you want to check out more the maths behind SQL.

Comment: No, cross join is called "relational Cartesian product" but it it isn't Cartesian product. The output of cross join contains tuple union/join/concatenations of elements of input sets. Cartesian product of n sets returns n-tuples, which here would be 2-tuples where each element is an input tuple. Cross join returns a certain subset of the Cartesian product of certain projections of input tables.