# Mathematical Explanation of the Difference between SQL Joins: Inner, Outer, Left, Right

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

#### Question

This question calls for a mathematically sound & intuitive explanation of [SQL joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) that clearly shows the difference between the following:

- Inner Join
- Left Join
- Right Join
- Full Outer Join

The explanation of joins should not misuse Venn diagrams. This is key. It should also be as accessible as possible to a computer programmer or mathematical beginner. We don't want to scare programmers away from mathematical concepts by using too much jargon. Of course, a little bit of maths is always necessary.

#### Motivation

The internet is rife with usages of Venn diagrams to explain SQL joins. As pointed out in the following articles, this leads to a grave misunderstanding of either Venn diagrams, SQL joins or both:

- https://towardsdatascience.com/can-we-stop-with-the-sql-joins-venn-diagrams-insanity-16791d9250c3
- https://blog.jooq.org/2016/07/05/say-no-to-venn-diagrams-when-explaining-joins/

As a website that many students of mathematics and computer science consult as a source of truth, it is our responsibility as a community to try everything in our power to propagate truth. Unfortunately, Venn diagram usage to explain a concept which is really Cartesian product at its core is all to rife.

Our own sister site, StackOverflow, is unfortunately part of this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join/38578#38578. While there are many amazing answers under that question, the prevailing belief on that site appears to be that joins are intersections/unions and Venn diagrams are appropriate to explain them. The top ranked and accepted answer uses Venn diagrams and intersection/union to explain joins.

While there may be *some* cases where join coincides with intersections and unions, it is not in *general* the case. I fear that people are simply seeing the special case and accepting the Venn diagram explanation. I fear they are then walking away with improper understanding of SQL joins and set theory.

I am hoping that by posting a question here, even a small percentage of people might be directed here instead of to another site that has SQL joins incorrectly explained using Venn diagrams. I am hoping that at least one of the Stack Exchange websites can have an accepted answer explaining SQL joins that is mathematically accurate, and potentially many other good alternative answers alongside it to provide different perspectives.

To be clear: I *think* I understand SQL joins myself. The purpose of this question is to create visibility and a source of truth for those new students of computer science and mathematics who might not understand them fully.

#### Related

[Is Cartesian Product same as SQL Full Outer Join?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668885/is-cartesian-product-same-as-sql-full-outer-join)

Comment: Yes, I asked myself the same questions back when I was a software developer. This may or may not answer your question, but have you heard of relational algebras? Relational algebras are basically the theoretical basis for many of the operations you see in database programming.

Comment: I give you the wikipedia link, which does have descriptions regarding outer joins, inner joins, and such. There are tons of other references :https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_algebra

Comment: @LordVader007 I know. I am sickened by these abuses of mathematics. However, I do sympathise that this is not an easy subject for a computer programmer to understand. I think I will start a bounty. I want to contribute in whatever small way I can to propagate truth on this matter.

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? This post doesn't actually ask a question & is addressing both your particular presentation & requesting others.

Comment: My question is: an explanation of SQL join that is mathematically sound an intuitive. But I want multiple answers. I posted up my own attempt at an answer which is incomplete.

Comment: To be clear, @philipxy, I'm pretty sure I understand joins. But I fear many, many others don't, and are misusing Venn diagrams to explain them. I want proper explanations to be clear and visible on the internet, particularly on the StackExchange family of sites.

Comment: Please clarify your post, via edits, not comments. I don't know what your last comment has to do with my comment. If you have an answer to a question you should post it as an answer. If you want answers that address your suggested answer then you should post that as a separate question.

Comment: @philipxy Good point. Done.

Comment: That does not solve the problems in my comment. PS Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of editing time. PS Adding to something unclear doesn't make it clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107739/discussion-between-colm-bhandal-and-philipxy).

Comment: Right now I don't see a benefit to chat because I think my comments are clear & clearly valid.

Comment: OK I'll post my answer then. I see what you mean.

Comment: "While there are many amazing answers under that question" No, all the questions there are clearly poor except mine, which is concise, complete & documented (but minimal & dry). [MartinSmith's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27458534/3404097) is not too bad, in that it actually fully defines the operators & their differences, but it's repetitive & has other problems. See my comments on posts there. (Moreover, as I have commented there, your added bonus details have muddled the question.) You have only to carefully read what is actually written in them.

Comment: @philipxy Martin Smith's answer is the best in my opinion. The repetitiveness is pedagogical in nature and I respect it.

Comment: yay "A join doesn't give you the intersection of anything.  It gives you a closure in a lattice".  Oh wait, that was me.

Comment: @nomen OK I finally found where you wrote that quote. But in fact an outer join is a union of inner join rows & a set or sets of null-extended rows. Although that's not what the bad answer you were commenting on was saying. (See my comments below the one you quote.) Also relational join is a lattice meet, not a lattice join.

Comment: @philipxy I have been meditating on this and yes, an outer join is indeed a union of left and right joins. So Venn diagrams do hae limited scope to describe this. But when people use the tables themselves as the two sets in the Venn diagram then it's game over for any credibility of the explanation. That's what I mean by "misuse" of Venn diagrams.

Comment: There is another way to go about this actually. Start with LEFT Join and then some symmetry and then define everything from there (using a Venn diagram of all things). I'll post an answer at some point if I get time... Or if somebody else does first, even better ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $A, B$ be sets.  We think of $A$ and $B$ as tables, and their elements as rows.  Each element of $x\in A$ is a list of data entries, one for each column of $A$.

(Edit: WLOG assume $A$ and $B$ do not have duplicate entries.  If they do, add a unique index column to each.)

Let $R$ be any relation, that is, a subset $R \subseteq A \times B$, where we write $a \sim \, b$ if $(a,b) \in R$.  In SQL $R$ corresponds to the statement that appears after "ON", e.g., `A.name = B.name` corresponds to the relation $x \sim y$ if and only if the entry in the `name` column of for a row $x \in A$ is the same as the `name` column in a row of $y \in A$.

Then $$A \operatorname{ INNER JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R = \{(a,b) \in A \times B \, |\, a \sim b\}\, (=R).$$

(Edit: Here $(a,b)$ represents the concatenation of the entries of rows $a$ and $b$, corresponding to `SELECT * FROM A JOIN B ON R`.  Of course the actual output may differ depending on the implementation.)

But here, if $a \in A$ is such that there is no corresponding $b$ such that $a \sim b$, then $a$ will not appear in the join.  If you take a left join, you want every $a$ to appear regardless.  So you add a special element $\operatorname{NULL}$ and add it to your relation. $\operatorname{NULL}$ obeys the rules

> $a \sim \operatorname{NULL}$ iff there is no $b \in B$ with $a \sim b$
>
> $\operatorname{NULL} \sim b$ iff there is no $a \in A$ with $a \sim b$

Now let $$\hat{A} = A \cup \{\operatorname{NULL}\},$$ $$\hat{B} = B \cup \{\operatorname{NULL}\}.$$

Then we have

$$A \operatorname{ INNER JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R = \{(a,b) \in A \times B \, | a \sim b\}$$
$$A \operatorname{ LEFT JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R = \{(a,b) \in A \times \hat{B} \, | a \sim b\}$$
$$A \operatorname{ RIGHT JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R = \{(a,b) \in \hat{A} \times B \, | a \sim b\}$$
$$A \operatorname{ OUTER JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R = \{(a,b) \in \hat{A} \times \hat{B} \, | a \sim b\}.$$

Thus we'll have the pairs $(a, \operatorname{NULL})$ appear on the left join whenever $a$ doesn't match any $b$, and $(\operatorname{NULL}, b)$ whenever $b$ doesn't match any $a$ in the right join. (note that we don't have $\operatorname{NULL} \sim \operatorname{NULL}$, so we never have $(\operatorname{NULL}, \operatorname{NULL})$.)

The reason that Venn diagrams are used to depict joins is that usually joins are usually done on relations as simple as the one given above, $R$ corresponding to `A.name = B.name`.  In that case, if $\text{names}(T)$ is the *set* of names that appear in a table $T$, that is, $\text{names}(T)$ = `SELECT DISTINCT names FROM T`, then

\begin{align*}\text{names}(A\operatorname{ INNER JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R) &= \text{names}(A)\cap \text{names}(B) \\
\text{names}(A\operatorname{ LEFT JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R) &= \text{names}(A)\\
\text{names}(A\operatorname{ RIGHT JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R) &= \text{names}(B)\\
\text{names}(A\operatorname{ OUTER JOIN } B \operatorname{ON} R) &= \text{names}(A)\cup \text{names}(B).\end{align*}

However, this completely loses sight of the fact that joins may be one-to-one, many-to-one, or many-to-many, and personally I've found those Venn diagrams more confusing than helpful when learning about joins.

Comment: This is not clear. Its formalization does not reflect the objects & operators involved. SQL tables are not relations & are not sets, this is part of the problem with trying to define its operators, and this post does not address all the relevant issues. Also DB tables/relations including those that ON conditions can be taken to denote are n-ary, not binary, and results of join are not Cartesian products of inputs. Even if tables were sets, the definitions would be wrong. Cardinality is not "lost sight of", it is irrelevant to the general case. Your Venn exposition is not clear. Etc.

Comment: Where are the definitions wrong? Can you be more specific?

Comment: Just work though any example. Start with the first sentence. Tables aren't sets they're bags.

Comment: Because it could contain duplicates? You could assume WLOG that rows are distinct by throwing in a unique index column to both tables.

Comment: What is your point? A correct presentation could be given. This isn't one. There are many, many problems with this post & I listed some in my 1st comment. But if you worked through an example & know how the operators act you'd find them. PS  Adding a null row to define the result doesn't work when exactly 1 input table is empty.

Comment: You made a fair point that there could be duplicates, and I'm happy to edit to fix it.  I don't know specifically what the other issues you have in mind are.  e.g., I don't know what you mean by n-ary relations here - AFAIK the data of a row of A JOIN B contains only data that could be found in a single row of A and a single row of B, not any third row.  That's why I represented it as a subset of $A \times B$.  You could of course define A JOIN B JOIN C etc., but that is not what I was defining.

Comment: Work through any example.

Comment: This really is an excellent example and exactly the kind of way I like joins to be explained. That said, there is still room for other answers, or even an extension of this answer, that have concrete real-world examples. My worry is that a computer programmer who has never seen any maths might just give up at the sight of this. As such, I would like to leave this question open a little longer rather than accepting this answer right away. But well done, again. The best explanation of joins on the web I've seen to date.

Comment: @ColmBhandal This answer is full of wrong things. It is not consistent with what SQL tables are or what JOINs do, and has other errors & vageness. I say the same to you as the poster--just work through any example. To quote myself from my comments on the SO question: "You are doing just what thousands of others have done--got a *vague impression* you (wrongly) *assume* makes sense."

Comment: @philipxy There is nothing vague about this explanation. It is crystal clear to me. So what you're saying is that it does not reflect the behaviour of SQL joins. Why not answer the question yourself with the correct mathematical characterisation of SQL joins and let's see the difference? Perhaps you can add some concrete examples. Make it easy for people to understand what you're trying to communicate to us, don't try to make people read your mind.

Comment: @ColmBhandal Work through any example.

Comment: @philipxy Inside my brain I find the explanation given here completely consistent with any example I can think of. I sense though that you have a counter-example in mind. So join the community and show it to us! You might help me/others learn.

Comment: @JairTaylor I think I finally see what philipxy is suggesting. Basically the formalism gets the "big picture" part of the join right, by using relational algebra. I think philipxy wanted the formalism to extend to how the join operator extends to individual records: how does a pair $(a, b)$ convert to a single record in the result table? And how are NULLs treated in this conversion?

Comment: @ColmBhandal Assuming you do a `SELECT * FROM`, $(a,b)$ corresponds to a concatenated list of the values of the columns in rows $a$ and $b$.  The column names may change etc. if some are repeated in $a$ and $b$, but this depends on the query language/implementation.

Comment: @JairTaylor I gotcha... just might be worth adding a tiny note to the answer. The answer is still useful as is though, so I wouldn't sweat it.

Comment: @ColmBhandal x cross join y & x outer-or-inner-join y on c are defined with x, y & the result being tables (with n-ary headings) holding (a bag of) n-ary rows without regard to any other select statement clauses, including select clauses. cross join is not Cartesian product.

Comment: @philipxy I worked through an example and I found that the information given in this answer is correct. If you think that working through an example will reveal a problem with this answer, please tell us *which* example to work through and what the problem is.

Comment: What is ×? Cross join is not Cartesian product. "Let R be any relation"--We have ON R & R is (more or less) a wff. With either columns or rows as variables--your choice is not clear. You abuse "R" to mean that wff & its extension. "any relation" does not mean "a subset R⊆A×B". Etc. Your writing is not clear. If you want a specific problem with your example pointed out, put it in your post to show what expressions have what values. I'm not particularly interested in convincing you of the problems or in pointing them all out, it's just likely you'll see some if you work an example in detail.

Comment: @philipxy The first thing Microsoft's Azure docs say in defining the cross join is: ["A cross join returns the Cartesian product of rows from the rowsets in the join."](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/u-sql/statements-and-expressions/select/from/joins/cross-join)  A [relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_relation) in math is described exactly as a subset of the Cartesian product. Specifying the actual grammatical structure of allowed formulas is not necessary to understand the abstract join.

Comment: @philipxy I'm sure you have a better technical understanding of joins than I do, so it would be nice if you would contribute an answer.  You're also free to downvote this answer if you like, or edit to fix errors.  In any case, I'll let others hash out the debate from here.

Comment: The web, including most product documentation, is not a good source of information, especially about relational DBs. Certain DBMS manuals are relatively good. "Cartesian product" gets misused in a relational context to mean cross join, but nevertheless cross join is not Cartesian product, it's just reminiscent of it. Similarly, DB relations are not math relations, depending on the algebra/language. Your post does not reflect semantics of SQL or proper use of formal notation. Bye.

Answer (score 1):

Jair Taylor has given us a precise mathematical formalism of the four type of joins in [his answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3659625/mathematical-explanation-of-the-difference-between-sql-joins-inner-outer-left/3664118#3664118), as called for. This answer supplements that one with a concrete example.

Suppose we have two tables, **BuildingPrice** and **Buyers**:

[image]

And suppose we want to know which buildings can be afforded by which buyers. We can do a SQL join. Here is the inner join SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM BuildingPrice JOIN Buyers ON AccountBalance >= Price
```

The `ON` condition characterises the relation Jair talks about in his answer. We can then visualise all four joins (with the same `ON` condition), in the following diagram:

[image]

In this diagram, we flip the Buyers table on its side so that its rows are now columns, i.e. we transpose it. We also add the special `NULL` element that Jair describes. This gives us the cross product, which is the rectangular area achieved by multiplying the columns in the transposed Buyers table, plus `NULL`, with the rows in the BuildingPrice table, plus `NULL`. All joins start with the inner join, the green area. The left, right and outer joins add extra elements as required.

Each element in the diagram that's included in the diagram is a pair of rows: one from `BuildingPrice` and one from `Buyers`. Of course, what's actually returned by a join is not a set of pairs of rows but a set of rows. So for any given pair, we convert it to a single row of the result table by simply taking the union of all the column to value mappings. For the NULL case, those mappings will all have a value of NULL. So for example, our LEFT join would result in this table:

[image]

### A Note on NULL

It is important that we have the correct, precise interpretation of `NULL` here, and what it means for the resulting records in the joined table. `WLOG` we'll just consider the `LEFT JOIN` case. Suppose we have an element $x$ of the left table which has no right table elements associated to it. This will, in Jair's characterisation, give rise to the pair $(x, $`NULL`$)$ being included in the join.

For the actual joined table though, we have to go a step further and convert that pair to a record i.e. a row in the resultant table. For that to work, we need to convert `NULL` to a column-mapping in the right table, where the value of each mapped column is `NULL`. So in this case, `NULL` is actually the map:

As correctly pointed out in the comments, the two tables will not in general have the same set of columns or even the same number of columns, so the meaning of NULL in the LEFT and RIGHT cases is different. WLOG, we're just considering the left case, in which the `NULL` actually means this mapping representing a row of the right table:

$($`Buyers.Name`$ \rightarrow$`NULL`$,$ `AccountBalance`$ \rightarrow$`NULL`$)$

Comment: This is unclear. You don't actually present how to read that diagram. Write a complete concise legend for the diagram including relating it to inputs & outputs of an operator. Give a tutorial separately. Argue pro/con separately. PS Yes a square is misleading vs a rectangle. Ideally better would be smaller, say 5x4. Explain white & pink. Suggest 2 lines to separate inner cells from margins. The "NULL" & its colour & its cell are just clutter. L & R are better than x & y. PS It's not clear just what rows are from input & are in output. (Consider putting the xi/y outside all cells.)

Comment: When & why Venns are & are not helpful is a separate issue from a presentation of & justification for this diagram. PS The clearer the diagram gets the more it looks like the Venn diagram for the correct use of a Venn diagram for illustrating output differences between the 4 joins for the special case of input sets. Because output rows are 1:1 with cells of certain colours. (The "2 lines" get extended to 2 rectangles = 2 sets.)

Comment: I can see how one would suspect one might want labels running vertically & horizontally that are input row values plus an all-null row. Having one shared "NULL" is probably not a clear way to do that. In general the axes use subrows of nulls of different lengths. I don't expect having one "NULL" standing in for both null subrows is going to work. PS It may turn out that most helpful is for each row & column to be labelled both by an input row value & a null. All-pink horizontal or vertical strips choose the null row for incorporation into output. (Details & "best" to be determined.)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative characterisation of joins starts with `LEFT JOIN` and defines everything from there. It is equivalent to Jair Taylor's formalism, just a different perspective. This definition is very formal so it should definitely be supplemented by other answers / concrete examples for a good intuition of `JOIN`.

### Definition: Values

Let's define the set $V$ as the set of all possible values in any possible SQL cell. So $V$ would be the union of all possible SQL types. The reason for doing this is so that we don't get bogged down in type-system considerations.

No matter what our universe of values is, we always assume a null value, call it $NULL$.

### Definition: Record(s)

Let's say we have a set of columns $C$. A record for $C$ is just a function from $C$ onto $V$. In computer science terms, imagine a dictionary or a map. Let's denote the set of all records for a column set $C$ as $R_C$:

$$R_C = C \rightarrow V$$

### Definition: Null Record

Let's say we have a set of columns $C$. We can define the null record for $C$, $NULL_C : R_C$ as follows:

$$NULL_C = \lambda c \mapsto NULL$$

That is, it is the function which maps every column $c : C$ to the value $NULL$.

### Definition: Table

Let's say we have a set of columns $C$. A table for $C$ is just a set of records for $C$. Let's denote the set of all such tables as $T_C$. Then:

$$T_C = \mathcal P(R_C)$$

Where $\mathcal P$ is just the symbol for the powerset, i.e. the set of all subsets, of a given set. So a table is just a subset of all possible records for a given set of columns.

**Note:** As Jair points out in his answer, although tables are in reality bags, not sets of records, we can always add an invisible column to the column set $C$ that must be unique, forcing a set representation. So WLOG, we'll continue with sets, which are easier to handle.

### Definition: Left Set Selector

Suppose we have two sets of columns $C$ and $D$. WLOG let's assume these sets are disjoint (in SQL, we can force column names to be disjoint by prepending the table name to get a fully qualified name). And suppose we have two tables $t_C : T_C$ and $t_D : T_D$. And suppose we are given any binary relation $R : \mathcal P(t_C \times t_D)$.

Then we can define a precursor to the left join. Define $S : t_C \rightarrow \mathcal P(t_C \times t_D)$:

$$S(r_C) = \{r_D : t_D | r_C R r_D\}$$

And then define our set selector $LS : \mathcal P(t_c \times (t_d \cup NULL_D))$

$$ LS(r_C) = \begin{cases} S(r_C) & \text{if }S(r_C) \neq \emptyset \\ 
                            NULL_D & \text{if }S(r_C) = \emptyset \end{cases} $$

### Definition: Left Join Precursor

Given column sets $C, D$, and a relation $R : \mathcal P(t_C \times t_D)$. The left join precursor $LJP : T_C \times T_D \rightarrow \mathcal P(T_C \times (T_D \cup \{NULL_D\}))$ can be defined as follows:

$$LJP(t_c, t_d) = \bigcup_{r_C : T_C} LS(r_C)$$

### Record Join

Suppose we have two records $r_C$ and $r_D$ on column sets $C$ and $D$ respectively. Then we can define the joined record on the set $C \cup D$ as:

$$J(r_C, r_D) = \lambda x \mapsto \begin{cases} r_C(x) & x : C \\ 
                             r_D(x) & x : D \end{cases} $$

### Definition: Left Join

Given column sets $C, D$, and a relation $R : \mathcal P(t_C \times t_D)$. The left join $L : T_C \times T_D \mapsto T_{C \cup D}$ can be defined as:

$$L(t_C, t_D) = \{J(r_C, r_D) : R_{C \cup D}| (r_C, r_D) : LJP(t_C, t_D)\}$$

### Definition: Right Join

The right join $RJ$ can be defined using symmetry and the left join:

$$RJ(t_C, t_D) = LJ(t_D, t_C)$$

### Definition: Inner Join

$$I(t_C, t_D) = RJ(t_C, t_D) \cap L(t_C, t_D)$$

### Definition: Outer Join

$$O(t_C, t_D) = RJ(t_C, t_D) \cup L(t_C, t_D)$$

### Venn Diagram Relating all Four Joins

[image]

The outer join is not labelled in the picture but it is the union of the areas of the two circles.

**NB: THE CIRCLES IN THIS VENN DIAGRAM ARE NOT THE ORIGINAL TABLES THAT WERE JOINED. PLEASE DO NOT GLANCE OVER THIS IMAGE AND MISTAKE THEM AS SUCH.**

Comment: "we can always add an invisible column to the column set C that must be unique" That doesn't work. Eg: The output of full join can be ((null,null),(null,null)). Explain how the row-values get put in the right zones/(sub)sets of the diagram. Don't forget to account for the fact that different inputs put the row-values in different places. Note also that this can be where inputs are sets yet the output is not, so even your (& the accepted answer's) argument assuming sets on input & output is wrong. PS There is no reason to expect answers within days of posting on SE.

Comment: @philipxy I'll address your last point first. I am assuming that my acceptance of Jair's answer has prompted you to think that I expect speedy answers to my question? The approach I take is to give it a window of a couple of days and accept an answer that, in my opinion, achieves the bulk of what the question is looking for.

However, I would be delighted if more answers came.

Comment: @philipxy I can't see yet where this formalism (and Jair's equivalent one) break down in the sense that you are pointing out. I think that you really need the space of an answer to flesh it out. I'm not doubting you, I just don't have enough brain power to visualise what you're saying. You're going to have to help me. And to echo the last point, I'm in no hurry for such an answer, so take your time.

Comment: @philipxy For now, can you give me an SQL query I can run that will return the pair of pairs of nulls that you reference? I'm intrigued... (Of course I don't expect it to be a pair of pairs in SQL, which I expect to flatten it out into a single record, but you get my point I hope)

Comment: ((null)) outer join ((null)) on x=y. ((null),(null)) left join ((7)) on x=y. ((null),(null)) left join ((null)) on x is null. I give these to motivate you to eliminate sloppiness in arguments & then find errors. PS My comment re quick answers was in response to some comment by you on some post re not getting answers. PS A Venn diagram can correctly illustrate if elements are instances of row value expressions 1:1 with output rows but extreme care is needed defining the zones as sets. Formal math isn't required. But the definition complexity means the Venn will be mostly misinterpreted.

Comment: This presentation is free of most of the problems in math & exposition in the accepted answer. This still doesn't account for inner & outer joins being of the form f(tc, td, w), begging the question of mapping between wff w & R, involving either row-valued or V-valued variables. But for what it finally states, all this math is simply unnecessary--whatever your left join is, we can easily either define your right, full & inner textually & so justify the Venn, or use the Venn to define your right, full & inner. More important, this misses the point.

Comment: The point is, SQL table bodies are not sets but bags, the functions you define are not the SQL functions by the same name & Venn diagrams do not denote bags. So you've said nothing about SQL + Venns. (And for SQL tables on input with bags that are sets, your full join is not correct, because the SQL output is not always a bag that is a set.) (A claim of WLOG is about certain argument(s) existing, but such a claim is better made after the case given in full, because it must be justified per & checked against the case given in full.)

Comment: @philipxy Do you have SQL statement please that contradicts this answer? I really don't want this answer to be incorrect, so I'd like to get to the bottom of this and iron it out, but I can't follow your examples in the comments. Please post a full counter-example somewhere on the internet or refer me to one that demonstrates where this example breaks down. You can do this, for example, by posting a Q&A style question here or on our sister site SO. Counterexample should contains tables, the exact contents of the tables, and the exact SQL run.

Comment: @philipxy The counterexample could be, for example, a question such as "Can we Use Sets to Characterise SQL Joins?" The answer would attempt to use sets as we have done, by assuming an invisible unique ID as we have done to avoid loss of generality, and then would arrive at some contradiction demonstrating why sets can't be used. If you are indeed correct, and you make this contribution, then you will be helping me and countless others understand joins.

Comment: You need to read some textbooks and a DBMS reference manual re SQL. Don't ask for yet another to be written. See the 3 free bookboon.com books by Hugh Darwen. Dozens of published academic information modelling & DB design textbooks are online free. (Manuals for languages & tools to record & use designs are not such textbooks.) (Nor are wiki articles or web posts.)  If you can't code those joins or don't know how to characterize SQL tables or joins you should be asking questions about being stuck doing so & shouldn't be trying to answer questions about SQL. Q&A isn't for teaching or education.

Comment: I agree certain Q&As like you are talking about would be helpful. Moreover, web, SO, dba.SE & SE relational model content is atrocious.

Comment: @philipxy I disagree with your sentiment that Q&A isn't for teaching or education. That is precisely what it is for, in a broad sense. I agree with your last comment that certain Q&As could be helpful. I am not going to read an entire textbook on SQL and I don't think others should have to either to get a clear understanding of joins. I would greatly appreciate if you would share your textbook knowledge in a succinct Q&A style answer, illuminate me on what's wrong with this and other posts, and help me and others learn, and perhaps reduce the amount of SQL bugs globally.

Comment: Questions asking for off-site resources are not valid SO question. You can learn more about what the site is for & what others think of that & what makes a good question etc googling the metas & help pages. PS I didn't say to read an entire book, and I did say to find out what basic things are & ask where stuck & to work through an example including for bags in your post, etc, but you haven't. Our comment exchanges show how Q&A is & should be limited.